# Best way to deal with the automatically recycled bitmaps on Activity pause

Tags: android

Most of my apps use a bitmaps in a SurfaceView class run by a thread, and some of the bitmaps are as big as the current screen resolution. I have noticed that if the activity is on pause Android may automatically recycle the big bitmaps to free the memory. So when one is in an app and clicks on home button and then opens the same app again, it may crash because the bitmap is no longer there.

From your experience what would be the best method to deal with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't dealed with such a situation, but my first try would be to call inside onResume

```
if(mBitmap.isRecycled()){ mBitmap = ... }
```

and reinstantiate in case it returns true

Comment: Thanks, I have just implemented something like this. When an app uses many bitmap images Android can remove big bitmaps at any point for no apparent reason except to free the memory perhaps, hence in the onDraw loop one has to check if the big bitmaps (e.g. backround image) are still there and reload them...